# Register which word pressed

Tags: c++

I have recently been working on a C++ project where the user enters text. The text is scraped from a dictionary and shown in a textbox when the user presses a word. The problem is that I don't know how to register which word is being pressed. Does anyone know how I could do this, and which GUI library I should use?

Comment: You can use Qt to do that, but maybe their are smaller library.

Comment: This is too broad without any code or example of what the UI should look like. It's not clear what "presses a word" means. Recommendations for libraries or other resources are off-topic.